# Combine two rows for SQL View

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's what I am trying to do. I have some data related to an item Id. I need to combine the rows like this:

[image]

But I am not really sure how to go about this in an efficient way. Where do I start? How can I roll the value to another row like this? The goal is to get it on the same line so further calculations can be used against it with the quantity in place against the charge Id it needs for our use case.

Comment: I assume you are partitioning the data by ACCOUNT_ID and I assume you are summing PLAN? are you want the data sorted by CHARGE_ID? for Type/Qty/StartDate are they things you want the first value of or are they part of the partition?

Comment: usualyy you use a group by , but you have to aggregate all column that are nit part of the group by. the only think i can see is the account_id and/or startdate. Besides here you should post data always in text form or as dbfiddle example.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions about what your are looking for, you probably want someth
ing like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id,
       FIRST_VALUE("type") OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS "type",
       FIRST_VALUE(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS qty,
       FIRST_VALUE(startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY startdate) AS startdate,
       SUM("plan") OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS "plan",
       FIRST_VALUE(charge_id) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS charge_id
FROM your_table;
```